# Wait till the http.get will return object

Tags: javascript, function, http, get

How i can wait, till http.get will return object ??

```
getData: function(){
    let obj = false;
    http.get("http://...")
      .accept("application/json")
      .end(function(err,res){
        if(err==null && res.ok){
          let js = JSON.stringify(res.body);
          obj = JSON.parse(js);
        }
      })
      return obj;
  },
```

this function i am calling `var obj = getData;` but i am still getting false, when i print the values, first its return false, and then object is assigned, so how wait till the object is assigned and then return object ??

Comment: use differed and promise in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method would be to use a fallback function.  You can use a promise but that requires extra:

Change the function to accept a callback function, then call that function when the get call has returned:

```
getData: function(cb){
  let obj = false;
  http.get("http://...")
    .accept("application/json")
    .end(function(err,res){
      if(err==null && res.ok){
        let js = JSON.stringify(res.body);
        obj = JSON.parse(js);

        if (cb)
          cb(obj);
      }
    });
},
```

then call it with:

```
getData(function(obj){  
    // do something here with the returned object.
});
```

Asyncronous programming, which http.get is, uses events in the form of callbacks - and promises.  So wait for http.get to return which is the event, then proceed once it returns.

Comment: This solution looks good, but what when i wana return false if the connection will not be accepted ??

Comment: can i do just if(cb) cb(obj); else cb(obj) ? edit: i tried, and it works well. thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: `if (cb)` is just a check to make sure cb has been passed, so as long as it has been then obj will either be an object or null / undefined.

Answer (score 0):

if your http.get call returns a promise obj then you can do something like this
change get data method to

```
getData: function(){
        let obj = false;
        return http.get("http://...")
          .accept("application/json");
      },
```

and the call it like

```
var obj = getData();
obj.end(function(err,res){
        if(err==null && res.ok){
          let js = JSON.stringify(res.body);
          obj = JSON.parse(js);
        }
      })
```